# How to lookup Github issue by ID instead of :user/:repo/issues:/number

Tags: github-api

The [documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#get-a-single-issue) shows that issues can only be requested with a known `user`, `repo` and issue `number` but I only have the issue's ID.

Repositories can be requested by ID as shown in this implementation [KnpLabs/php-github-api/pull/579](https://github.com/KnpLabs/php-github-api/pull/579).

Is there any way to request an issue by its ID only?

I was hoping issues could be requested like so `https://api.github.com/issues/123456`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the issue number is publicly exposed.

The issue ID is not, unless you are using:

- the [GHTorrent project](http://ghtorrent.org/) (for public repos)
- a [BigQuery for GitHub](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2016/06/GitHub-on-BigQuery-analyze-all-the-open-source-code.html)

Both would help finding the issue number based on the issue query, but that is certainly not as straightforward as a `https://api.github.com/issues/<ID>`...

Comment: I am using [octokit/rest.js](https://github.com/octokit/rest.js) and the issue ID is returned as part of the response. It appears the library is a simple abstraction over [Github's API V3](https://developer.github.com/v3/) so I am guessing the ID is actually exposed on all libraries using the public API. By exposed,  you mean an exposed API endpoint that takes an issue ID?

Comment: Nice! How is it exposed/retrieved?

Comment: [get and list endpoints](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/) returns a field called `id` on each issue but it just doesn't appear to be consumable. A repo's ID is consumable using `https://api.github.com/issues/{ID of issue}` though.

Comment: @ThomasPotaire OK, so the links I am mentioning in the answer would still apply in this instance.